# uma div dentro de outra div com position absolute vai ter position absolute tambem?

Tags: css

Se eu tiver uma div dentro de outra div:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

E pra div1 eu definir position absolute:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

A div2 também vai ter position absolute?

Comment: Sim, isso se chama efeito cascata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nem por isso. Qualquer elemento html tem `position` como `static`, a menos que seja indicado outro valor explicitamente. [Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position), [Fonte 2](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)

Também é possível de confirmar isto como o html de exemplo que colocou utilizado o inspeccionar do navegador e acedendo aos valores de css calculados (computed):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]